# DIV mask implemented in JavaScript/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Mask.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mask.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mask.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1" style="margin: 5px; border: 1px solid red; height: 100px; width: 500px;"></div>
        <div id="div2" style="margin: 5px; border: 1px solid blue; height: 100px; width: 500px">
            <div id="div3" style="margin: 5px; border: 1px solid red; height: 88px; width: 235px; float:left;"></div>
            <div id="div4" style="margin: 5px; border: 1px solid green; height: 88px; width: 235px; float:left;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mask.js

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.Mask = function () {

    if ($(this).find('.Mask').length > 0) return null;
        var __ctrl = $(this)[0];
        if (__ctrl.tagName != 'DIV') return null;

        var containerCssPaddingTop = $(__ctrl).css('padding-top');
        var containerCssPaddingRight = $(__ctrl).css('padding-right');
        var containerCssPaddingBottom = $(__ctrl).css('padding-bottom');
        var containerCssPaddingLeft = $(__ctrl).css('padding-left');

        $(__ctrl).css('position', 'relative');
        $(__ctrl).css('overflow', 'hidden');

        var mask = '<div class="Mask"><div class="MaskContent"><img src="PleaseWait.gif"/></div></div>';
        $(__ctrl).prepend(mask);

        var m = $(this).find('.Mask');
        var mc = $(this).find('.MaskContent');

        m.css('margin-top', '-' + containerCssPaddingTop);
        m.css('margin-right', '-' + containerCssPaddingRight);
        m.css('margin-bottom', '-' + containerCssPaddingBottom);
        m.css('margin-left', '-' + containerCssPaddingLeft);

        // The 16 just comes from the fact that the image displayed is 32x32
        mc.css('left', m.width()/2 - 16 + "px");

        var toReturn = {
            RemoveMask: function () {
                m.remove();
            }
        };

        return toReturn;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

mask.css

```
.Mask {
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse farthest-side, #FFFFFF 0%, #EEEEEE 100%);
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;    
}

.MaskContent {
    background: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

The real code I would like reviewed/criticized is in Mask.js and Mask.css

The idea is that this extends jQuery so you can block a div while it is being updated.

You would use it by running

```
v = $('#div1').Mask()
```

then, to remove it, one would do

```
v.RemoveMask();
```

Comment: Quick comment: PascalCase is only for constructors which are meant to be called with `new`. All other methods should use **camelCase**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine to me. Just a couple minor points:

1. Why do you change the `div`'s `position` to `relative`? If the function is called on a `div` with absolute positioning, it would mess up the layout. And you should revert the CSS changes on `RemoveMask()` to what they were when `Mask()` was called because the `div`'s content might depend on a certain `overflow` value.
2. If the `div` changes size while masked, the image will no longer be horizontally centered. I would suggest using CSS instead of JS to center it:

   ```
   .MaskContent {
     background: none;
     position: absolute;
     width: 32px;
     height: 32px;
     top: 30%;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -16px;
     z-index: 5;
   }
   ```
3. Your mask background currently only supports webkit browsers; you should add the CSS3 variations for the other browsers.